# Chemical characteristics of taste

Tags: flavor, taste, chemistry

I know this is probably a quirky question for this forum, but here goes. I'm getting into home brewing, and today I stumbled a cross the website for American Society for Brewing Chemists (ASBC) http://www.asbcnet.org/checksample/beer_analysis.htm. The page I just linked to is for the beer analysis service offered by ASBC. For the analysis, they test 32 different properties of the beer. Does anyone know if there is a known way to quantify or approximate the taste of a beer just with these 32 properties? Again, sorry if this is out of place for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot chemical compounds that contribute to the overall taste/aroma/etc of a beer let alone the proportions of each said compounds. Unless those 32 tests are incredibly comprehensive, I am guessing it could probably at only guess at beer category. The yeast make up around 600 chemical compounds alone. Most of those compounds are barely perceivable by taste/aroma so if any of the proportions move around, the flavors could drastically change.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I love craft beer, and I'm taking a graduate level machine learning course at my university. I'm just curious as to if anybody has ever tried to map quantifiable beer properties to say Beer Advocate ratings. Conceptually, you could predict the rating of a beer without needing to taste it. This assumes, however, that there is a way to roughly quantify beer taste by doing chemical analysis.